# Angularjs + Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, factory, angular-promise

I am using Angularjs, I have two api in method in factory method. I tried to access that two method one by one. but its not working.

We need to first print test1 then print test2.

Controller code:

```
app.controlle("Test").function($scope, factoryMethod) {
    factoryMethod.test1().then(function(data) {

        console.log(data);
        console.log("test1");

    }).then(factoryMethod.test2().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("test2");

    })).catch(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Factory code:

```
app.factory("factoryMethod", function (){
    //code for test1 
    //code for test2
});
```

Currently the console log print the following order:
1. test2
2. test1

Expecting test1 and than test2

Comment: Move your entire `factoryMethod.test2().then(function(data) {...})` into the first callback function.

Comment: how can get the response for test1 function ? pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be done like this. look at snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.factory("factoryMethod",['$q',function($q){
  
  var  test1 = function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
    
         deferred.resolve("test1");
          
          return deferred.promise;
    }
    
  var  test2 = function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
    
         deferred.resolve("test2");
          
          return deferred.promise;
    }
    
  return {
      test1 : test1,
      test2 : test2
    }
}]);

app.controller("Test",function($scope, factoryMethod){
  
  var promise =  factoryMethod.test1();
  
  promise.then(function(data){
  
    console.log(data);
    
    factoryMethod.test2().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
        },function(error){
    console.log("error from test 2");
})
      },function(error){
   console.log("error from test 1")
})
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="Test">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is in controller how can handle error?

Comment: see , i have updated my snippet , and handled error in controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.controlle("Test").function($scope, factoryMethod) {
    factoryMethod.test1().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("test1");
        factoryMethod.test2().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("test2");
        });
    }).catch(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controlle("Test").function($scope, factoryMethod) {
    var myData = factoryMethod.test1().then(function(data) {

        // Return data from factoryMethod1
        return data;

        // Or return the data from factoryMethod2 (remove the return statement above if you want this
        return factoryMethod.test2().then(function(data) {

            return data;
        });
    }).catch(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```